# SQLite no such table exception. GreenDao Android

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: <table name> (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT T."<param>",T."<param>",T."<param>",T."<param>",T."<param>" FROM "<param>" T  WHERE T."<param>"=?
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:921)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:532)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:68)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1402)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
   at org.greenrobot.greendao.database.StandardDatabase.rawQuery(StandardDatabase.java:32)
   at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.Query.list(Query.java:88)
   at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.QueryBuilder.list(QueryBuilder.java:427)
```

table name - is the name of table of the database (it doesn't matter)

param - is the name of property (it doesn't matter)

The problem is that this issue happens only for **small amount** of users.

**Important**: This crash isn't related to scheme changes. The app starts crashing with this exception starting the first build with database.

The database is created during Dagger application component creation (onCreate method of the application) using GreenDao.

I'm looking for ideas, what could be the root cause of that issue.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a race condition where in a small number of cases, the SQLite database hasn't yet been initialized?

Comment: i'm investigating race condition right now, but it's really hard to imagine that case :) anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: perhaps add logging an extract from the sqlite_master table just before the query in question, this would then list/log all of the tables. perhaps even compare against this to see if the table being processed does exist.

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok Did you ever find a cause for this?

Comment: @carloshwa, we didn't find a root cause. we released a new version of the application, where we update a db scheme version. A migration strategy was to drop all existing tables and create new (we had such an amazing opportunity) tables. The app in live for ~1 week and i don't see any crashes.

Comment: We've also encountered this issue. Turned out our issue was that the first version of the database didn't contain the missing table in question. We had to explicitly specify TABLE_DAO.createTable(db, true) in the onUpgrade method when migrating.